# java NullPointerException existed Image

Tags: java, image, file, nullpointerexception

What I want to do is when the user selects an image, this image must be copied to a specific folder and then use the image.

this is what I use to copy the image:

```
Files.copy(
    Paths.get("C:/../img.png"),
    Paths.get("C:/../src/bgs").resolve(array[array.length-1]),
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

which works fine. The problem is that if I use the image immediately after this command, I get `NullPointerException` (I don't have this problem if I use something like `Thread.sleep(2500)` between the two commands). So basically I need a way to check if the file is ready to be used.

So far I used the following code

```
// copy file
File f = new File(new_path);
sout(f.exists());
// use file
Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
    getClass().getResource("/bgs/img.png"));
```

which prints true, but when I use it I get `NullPointerException` again.. any ideas?

Exception:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

Comment: Files.copy is not asynchronous in Java. Check to see if you are instantiating your image wrong. Can you post the code where you are instantiating the image which is causing the null pointer?

Comment: check the edited question. The instantiation is not wrong cause it is used multiple times in the code.. maybe Files.copy and Toolkit. do not work together

Comment: Can you also post the exception stack? Thanks!

Comment: ... and tell us which line the NPE is thrown on.

Comment: edited again, tbh I am not sure the line which the npe is thrown on, but when I try to use this Image as background, I get a blank background

Comment: Well it seems like you didn't post the full stack trace which should have at least showed us where exactly it was thrown..

Comment: no, the trace is exactly what I posted

Comment: the exception is thrown on `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()...` because if I set another image in there, I get no NPE

Comment: Why are you copying the file into the src directory? If you're doing this within the same runtime context, it's unlikely your code will see the resource, as src directory may not be within the class path

Comment: I need the file to be copied in case the user selects this file and delete it later

Comment: There won't be a `src` directory when you deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, so just in case someone else faced this, here is what I did:

replace

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/bgs/img.png"));
```

with

```
ImageIO.read(new File("bgs/img.png"));
```

be carefull with the path

> "/bgs/img.png"
>
> "bgs/img.png"

Comment: In other words the file wasn't where you claimed it was.

Comment: let me say it this way.. if I run again the previous code (so the image is already moved where I wanted) it works fine.. so it is not about the directory (I m talking about the code of the question including `Toolkit...`